# VBA - How to get around carriage returns

Tags: vba, excel

I think this should be fairly easy to do but I am struggling:- I have a cell with data which is separated by multiple carriage returns. I always want the second line of data but I am unsure how to pull just this out? Data example is like below:

```
Line 1: This line can be any length
Line 2: Same with this one
Line 3: so on
Line 4: and so forth
Line 5: etc
```

Thanks,

James

Comment: Split it using `VbCrlf` and access the `1` st element of the array.
Like if you do `cet = Split(cells(1,1).value, vbcrlf)` then `Msgbox cet(1)` will give you the second line.

Comment: `vbCrlf` might not work. In this case you can try `Chr(10)`: `Debug.Print Split(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").Value2, Chr(10))(1)`.

Answer (score 1):

With data in **A1**, in another cell enter:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A1,CHAR(10),REPT(" ",999)),2*999-998,999))
```

[image]

If this does not work, use `CHAR(13)`.

To do this in VBA:

```
Public Function SecondLine(s As String) As String
    s = Replace(s, Chr(13), Chr(10))
    s = Replace(s, Chr(10) & Chr(10), Chr(10))
    SecondLine = Split(s, Chr(10))(1)
End Function
```

Comment: @Mat'sMug  It **might** work...............but it you are pasting material into a worksheet, the breaks might be *ASCII10* or *ASCII13* or even both.........the VBA should work either way.